# how to change display infor customer?

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

I proceed to connect 2 phtml files into one file to display. and it appears  2 buttons to save different to 2 action? I want only one button SAVE

Comment: If I understand you well, you would like the two forms to be displayed on the same page, and only have one button to save all the different informations ?

Comment: yes!! sorry i am beginner with magento

Comment: This will not be an easy thing to do because the two forms are not processed in the same function.
In order to do that, you will have to modify the two forms to make only one of them, and create a new action in the controller, that will process all the information at the same time.

Comment: I could find to handle file somewhere?